# How set a valid publishable key with Ajax ? - for STRIPE

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm using `stripe` with checkout but when i want to pay it return this error

**You did not set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key.**

I have 3 files (`config.php` - `stripeIPN.php` and the `html` where is button)

---

**config.php**

```
require_once "stripe-php-master/init.php";

$stripeDetails = array(
    "secretKey" =>  "sk_test_xxx",
    "publishableKey" => "pk_test_xxx"
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripeDetails['secretKey']);

$pubkey = json_encode($stripeDetails['publishableKey']); 
return $pubkey;
```

---

**stripeIPN.php**

```
require_once "config.php";

\Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
   "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "eur",
    "description" => "",
    "source" => $token
));
```

---

**html**

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <div id="button-stripe-vab">
        <form action="stripeIPN.php" method="POST">
            <script id="stripe-link"
                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" 
                data-key=""
                data-amount=""
                data-name=""
                data-description=""
                data-image="image.png"
                data-locale="auto"
                data-label="Pay with card">
            </script>
        </form>
    </div>
```

in `data-key` i should to add my **publishable key** and in effect, the payment works, if i write it.
But i want to add it with `Ajax:

```
$.ajax({    
    type: "POST",   
    url: "config.php",  
    dataType:"json",    
    success: function (result) { //se funziona
        var pubkey = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));    
        $('#stripe-link').attr("data-key",pubkey);              
    }
});
```

I know my code is good because ajax works and with firebug i know that `data-key` after ajax has my **publishable key** but why stripe button return error ?
I have a doubt: maybe is it possible that the stripe button (so the DOM) is created before the execution of ajax?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're using data-key within Your success response. What is Your aim? when you want to use it?

Comment: @ripa i'm not really good with ajax...you say me i shoud not to use data-key in success response ? i want to extrapolate data key from config.php with ajax

Comment: @ripa that ajax is inside ready event

Comment: ok - got it. check my answer. I'm posting

Comment: @ripa thanks i'm waiting

Answer (score -1):

try below:-

```
var pubKey = "Your_key_here";

 $.ajax({    
   type: "POST",   
   url: "config.php",  
   dataType:"json", 
   data: { data_key: pubKey }   
   success: function (result) { //se funziona
      var pubkey = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));    

   }
});
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense what you wrote ....if I have to bring my public key back into the .js file then I should directly write it in the html. I don't think you understood my problem ...

Comment: this is the only format - how value will be passed in ajax file. you can google it. if you don't want this way then you have to think other way. not ajax. try SESSION